# How to simulate a key press and mouse click in C++

Tags: macos, cocoa

How can I simulate a mouse click / key press in C++? When I run the program I want it to click the left mouse and press "A". Thanks!
(I'm making this program for MacOSX)

Comment: Nothing, I haven't found anyway to do it.

Comment: What are you using for keyboard/mouse input?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: There's nothing else to understand. What method are you using for keyboard input? Plain `cin`? Could you show us some code where you're reading from the input?

Comment: @user1231958, To make sure we're all on the same page, check out the Windows version of the function the OP wants: [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx). Before I'm asked, no, I don't develop for macs, so I have no idea what equivalent is there.

Comment: I was thinking OP could "buffer" the input to one or many variables, and then that or those variables could be read from some function to determine the action. But, if OP wants to simulate the input, then he just tells the code where he needs to simulate to input data directly into the variables. But I need to know first how he's reading the data from the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: I need a subroutine that presses any key or clicks a mouse button

Comment: Are you feeding the mouse clicks and key presses to your self or another process?

Comment: To the mouse location on screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do any programming for OSX but I think this is what you are looking for:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html

In particular CGEventPost